# Dynamic routing and lifecycle in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with dynamic routing in react.
I'm fetching some data from a third-party API. I have my dynamic route to be something like this

`<Route path="/:id" component = {item} />`

In the item component, I get the value in `params.id` and use that id to fetch my data in

`componentDidUpdate(){ fetchData(this.props.match.params.id);}`

The issue I'm having now is that whenever I try to visit another route of the same format `/:id` from the Item component, the params changes to the new id passed but still retains the old content for the old id. I believe componentDidmount wasn't called since i'm in that same item component. the component wasn't remounted but just updated. What can I do?

Comment: Are you setting the data in state? Can you provide more info on how you're maintaining state variable and the data format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the api call in `componentDidMount` as well as in `componentDidUpdate` with class component. Once you fetch the data, you have to set it in state of the component to visually see it.

```
componentDidmount() {
  fetchData(this.props.match.params.id);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  if(prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    fetchData(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
}
```

If you rather use react hooks + functional component, this will be simplified for you. You can use `useState` to maintain data in the state.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
const YourComponent = props => {
    const { id } = props.match.params;
    // This will run every time id changes.
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(id);
    }, [id]); 

    return (
        <>
            Your api call
        </>
    );
};
```